# CSS calc: DIV with any width given from some other class, minus px

Tags: css

I have a div like this:

`<div class="w25 box">...</div>`

.w25 sets the width to 25% of the parent. But i also have .w33, .wXX ...

.box should make the look of that div like a box and that box visually needs some horizontal additional margin compared to a blank div without the .box class. But that added margins make the box wider than 25%, so it wraps earlier than non-box-divs.

so i would like to do this:

`.box { width: calc( AnyWidthItGotFrom_wXX – 20px ); margin: 0 10px; }`

The long way alternative is to create not only .wXX classes, but also .boxXX classes that do the job independently, but it's more CSS to create and maintain ...

(alternate take: i'm trying to achive what box-sizing: margin-box; would do horizontally, if it existed)

Comment: Can you share the complete code! Also, try `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: Simply set the width of `.w25` css class to `width: calc(25% - 20px)` giving your `.box` element always has `margin: 0 10px;`? https://jsfiddle.net/k6tsaevL/

Comment: You could set a padding instead of a margin, so you won't need to make width calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the classes `.wxx` to define a CSS variable that set the width, and use that variable in the .box class which defines a margin variable

```css
.w25 { --width: 25%; }
.w33 { --width: 33%; }
.w50 { --width: 50%; }

.box {
   --margin: 10px;
   width: calc(var(--width, 100%) - (var(--margin, 0) * 2));
   margin: 0 var(--margin, 0);
   border: 1px #ccc dashed;
}
```

```html
<div class="w25 box">25%</div>
<div class="w33 box">33%</div>
<div class="w50 box">50%</div>
<div class="box">100% by default</div>
```

doing so the `.wxx` classes are still responsible to define the value for `width`, but this is actually set on the `.box` element.

Comment: this is fantastic! I didn't know i could set a variable in one class, and then use it in another one that is assigned to the same html node! 

To clarify my question a bit: what i wanted is to make the width equal for both .box- and non-box divs with the same width class (and responsive and all), but make the box appear slightly smaller with the additional margins. With the variables, i can now do exactly that, it works like a charm.